# How do you parse an IP address string to a uint value in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, networking, iphelper

I'm writing C# code that uses the windows IP Helper API. One of the functions I'm trying to call is "[GetBestInterface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365920(VS.85).aspx)" that takes a 'uint' representation of an IP. What I need is to parse a textual representation of the IP to create the 'uint' representation.

I've found some examples via Google, like [this one](http://www.justin-cook.com/wp/2006/11/28/convert-an-ip-address-to-ip-number-with-php-asp-c-and-vbnet/) or [this one](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/internet/article.php/c10651), but I'm pretty sure there should be a standard way to achieve this with .NET. Only problem is, I can't find this standard way. IPAddress.Parse seems to be in the right direction, but it doesn't supply any way of getting a 'uint' representation...

There is also a way of doing this using IP Helper, using the [ParseNetworkString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb408412(VS.85).aspx), but again, I'd rather use .NET - I believe the less I rely on pInvoke the better.

So, anyone knows of a standard way to do this in .NET?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert an IPv4 address into a integer in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/461742/how-to-convert-an-ipv4-address-into-a-integer-in-c) as [nt. pointed out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37231/588306)?

Comment: You shouldn't be relying on the fact that an IP address can fit i a 32-bit number. Some IP addresses are 128-bit. And by hard-coding a dependency on 32-bit addresses: you limit how useful your system is.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

MSDN [says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.getaddressbytes.aspx) that IPAddress.Address property (which returns numeric representation of IP address) is obsolete and you should use [GetAddressBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.getaddressbytes.aspx) method.

You can convert IP address to numeric value using following code:

```
var ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("some.ip.address");
var ipBytes = ipAddress.GetAddressBytes();
var ip = (uint)ipBytes [3] << 24;
ip += (uint)ipBytes [2] << 16;
ip += (uint)ipBytes [1] <<8;
ip += (uint)ipBytes [0];
```

**EDIT:**
As other commenters noticed above-mentioned code is for IPv4 addresses only.
IPv6 address is 128 bits long so it's impossible to convert it to 'uint' as question's author wanted.

Comment: Are you sure about the four indices' order? it seems to me that byte with index 0 should be shifted 24 bits and not the one with index 3..

Comment: Or instead of last 4 lines, use: `BitConverter.ToUInt32(ipBytes, 0)`
See this fiddle on how to convert it to use network byte order that increments naturally as IP addresses goes: https://dotnetfiddle.net/eZguXl

Answer (score 18):

Shouldn't it be:

```
var ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("some.ip.address");
var ipBytes = ipAddress.GetAddressBytes();
var ip = (uint)ipBytes [0] << 24;
ip += (uint)ipBytes [1] << 16;
ip += (uint)ipBytes [2] <<8;
ip += (uint)ipBytes [3];
```

?

Answer (score 15):

```
var ipuint32 = BitConverter.ToUInt32(IPAddress.Parse("some.ip.address.ipv4").GetAddressBytes(), 0);`
```

This solution is easier to read than manual bit shifting.

See [How to convert an IPv4 address into a integer in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461742/how-to-convert-an-ipv4-address-into-a-integer-in-c)

Comment: BitConvertor.ToUINt32() takes two parameters (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint32.aspx)

Comment: Whoever tried to edit this answer please don't try editing code, even if incorrect because of typo just add a comment to inform the user who the answer belongs to, and don't go deleting the rest of the answer to just say why you did it.

Answer (score 5):

Also you should remember that [IPv4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4) and [IPv6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) are different lengths.

Answer (score 2):

Correct solution that observes Endianness:

```
var ipBytes = ip.GetAddressBytes();
ulong ip = 0;
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
{
    ip = (uint) ipBytes[0] << 24;
    ip += (uint) ipBytes[1] << 16;
    ip += (uint) ipBytes[2] << 8;
    ip += (uint) ipBytes[3];
}
else
{
    ip = (uint)ipBytes [3] << 24;
    ip += (uint)ipBytes [2] << 16;
    ip += (uint)ipBytes [1] <<8;
    ip += (uint)ipBytes [0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Byte arithmetic is discouraged, as it relies on all IPs being 4-octet ones.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.Net.IPAddress ipAddress = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.1");

byte[] bytes = ipAddress.GetAddressBytes();
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length ; i++)
       Console.WriteLine(bytes[i]);
```

Output will be 
192
168
1
1

Answer (score 1):

Complete solution:

```
public static uint IpStringToUint(string ipString)
{
    var ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(ipString);
    var ipBytes = ipAddress.GetAddressBytes();
    var ip = (uint)ipBytes [0] << 24;
    ip += (uint)ipBytes [1] << 16;
    ip += (uint)ipBytes [2] <<8;
    ip += (uint)ipBytes [3];
    return ip;
}

public static string IpUintToString(uint ipUint)
{
    var ipBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(ipUint);
    var ipBytesRevert = new byte[4];
    ipBytesRevert[0] = ipBytes[3];
    ipBytesRevert[1] = ipBytes[2];
    ipBytesRevert[2] = ipBytes[1];
    ipBytesRevert[3] = ipBytes[0];
    return new IPAddress(ipBytesRevert).ToString();
}
```

Reverse order of bytes:

```
public static uint IpStringToUint(string ipString)
{
    return BitConverter.ToUInt32(IPAddress.Parse(ipString).GetAddressBytes(), 0);
}

public static string IpUintToString(uint ipUint)
{
    return new IPAddress(BitConverter.GetBytes(ipUint)).ToString();
}
```

You can test here:

https://www.browserling.com/tools/dec-to-ip

http://www.smartconversion.com/unit_conversion/IP_Address_Converter.aspx

http://www.silisoftware.com/tools/ipconverter.php

Answer (score 0):

I have never found a clean solution (i.e.: a class / method in the .NET Framework) for this problem. I guess it just isn't available except the solutions / examples you provided or Aku's example. :(