# Fastest way to get numerical value of the request's IP Address in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, client, ip, uint

What would be the fastest way to get the numerical format (**NOT THE STRING FORMAT**) of the client?

```
string format  : 223.255.254.0
numeric format : 3758095872
```

I can postcompute this by some code like

```
    static public uint IPAddressToLong(string ipAddress)
    {
        var oIP = IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress);
        var byteIP = oIP.GetAddressBytes();


        var ip = (uint)byteIP[0] << 24;
        ip += (uint)byteIP[1] << 16;
        ip += (uint)byteIP[2] << 8;
        ip += byteIP[3];

        return ip;
    }
```

based on the Request.UserHostAddress string but I was hoping that IIS or ASP.NET precomputes this and it's somewhere hidden in the HttpContext.

Am I wrong?

Comment: You'll probably get all your answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/461742/how-to-convert-an-ipv4-address-into-a-integer-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HttpContext does not seem to be doing any more magic than what you already see: a string value in `HttpRequest.UserHostAddress`

**Some background info:**

`HttpContext.Current.Request` is of type `System.Web.HttpRequest` which takes a `System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest`as parameter when instantiated.

The `HttpWorkerRequest` is an abstract class instantiated by hosting implementations like, in case of IIS, `System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest` which then implements the abstract method `GetRemoteAddress()` of `HttpWorkerRequest` which is internally used by `HttpRequest.UserHostAddress`.

`IIS7HttpWorkerRequest` knows that `REMOTE_ADDR` is the IIS property it needs to read and, after going through a few more layers of abstraction while passing around the request context, it all finally ends in calling `MgdGetServerVariableW(IntPtr pHandler, string pszVarName, out IntPtr ppBuffer, out int pcchBufferSize);` in webengine.dll which simply writes a string of length `pcchBufferSize` into `ppBuffer` containing the same stuff you get from `HttpRequest.UserHostAddress`.

Since i doubt that there are other parts in the HttpContext that get fed request-sender related information, i'm assuming you'll have to keep doing your own magic for conversion for which there are plenty of ideas in the link i posted in the comments.