# IP Address Parameter in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a stored procedure that inserts a few columns into a database, IP Address, Name, Comments. I am not sure how to get the ip address of the users machine. Perhaps I am to create a variable of the same type (INT) and then store the IP Address in there. I am kinda of lost on this one.

```
static int IPAddress()
{ 
get { return Request.UserHostAddress; }; 
}//How do I pass from here into my stored procedure?


                cmdI.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@IPAddress", cmdI));
                cmdI.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", cmdI));
                cmdI.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Comments", cmdI));
```

Comment: UserHostAddress is a string.  What is the data tpe of IPAddress in the database?

Comment: What about IPv6? See [Returning an IPv4 Address in an IPv6-Enabled Environment](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/071807-1.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the IP Address from a string to an int; see [How to convert an IPv4 address into a integer in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461742/how-to-convert-an-ipv4-address-into-a-integer-in-c)

However, I would change the DB to store IP address as a string.  This way you will support IPv6.

Comment: Thats because you are storing them as an `int`.

Comment: i converted the db to nvarchar(50) and still get it

Answer (score -1):

IP address is indeed a representation of a 32bit int and can be stored in the db as such

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/461742/how-to-convert-an-ipv4-address-into-a-integer-in-c