# Convert IP range to range of CIDR addresses c#

Tags: c#, ip, cidr

I have the following issue : i need to convert range of `IP` addresses into range of `CIDR` addresses without losses of addresses. For example, 
if i have the range `1.1.1.3 - 1.1.1.7`, i can convert it into

```
 1.1.1.1/29
```

using `IPNetwork` library, but if i will convert 
`1.1.1.1/29` to range again i get `1.1.1.1 - 1.1.1.6`.
How could i divide ranges to get a few ranges in `CIDR` format without losses ?
Will be good if you can show me any `C#` code to perform it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert IP range to Cidr in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13508231/how-can-i-convert-ip-range-to-cidr-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

using the IPNetwork2 nuget package, you could subnet into /32 and iterate over the result ips :

Example 8 of documentation  :

```
IPNetwork wholeInternet = IPNetwork.Parse("1.1.1.1/29");
IPNetwork ips = IPNetwork.Subnet(wholeInternet, 32);

Console.WriteLine("All  :");

foreach (IPNetwork ip in ips)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", ip);
}
```

Output

```
All  :
1.1.1.0
1.1.1.1
1.1.1.2
1.1.1.3
1.1.1.4
1.1.1.5
1.1.1.6
1.1.1.7
```