# How to convert IP number to IPV6 using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, ip, ipv6, ip2location

I have CSV containing IP number's related to IPv6 and I am reading and converting them to IPv6 ip address which is failing at the moment.

I am using below code but getting error:

> Cannot convert value "281470698520576" to type "System.Net.IPAddress". Error: "Specified argument was
> out of the range of valid values.

```
function Convert-NumberToIP
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$number
    )

    [Int64] $numberInt = 0
    
    if([Int64]::TryParse($number, [ref]$numberInt))
    {
        if(($numberInt -ge 0) -and ($numberInt -le 0xFFFFFFFFl))
        {
            #([IPAddress] $numberInt).ToString()
            $ipBytes = ([IPAddress]$numberInt).GetAddressBytes()
            [array]::Reverse($ipBytes)
            ([IPAddress]$ipBytes).IPAddressToString
        }
    }
}

$startIP = Convert-NumberToIP -number '281470698520576'
$endIP = Convert-NumberToIP -number '281470698520580'
```

Comment: Remember that IPv6 addresses are 128-bit unsigned integers, not 64-bit integers.

Comment: @RonMaupin when I am using `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` it say's `The numeric constant is not valid`

Comment: Correct. Most languages do not directly support 128-bit integers.

Comment: It's not a good idea to modify a question such that it invalidates existing answers. Instead, accept an answer that solves your original question and then post a new question.

Comment: @zett42 thanks sure I will do and create a new question.

Comment: @NaveenKumar if the question was answered, please accept an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use a 128bit integer in PowerShell you can leverage .NET `System.Numerics.BigInteger` class. Like this:

`$ipv6Decimal  = [System.Numerics.BigInteger]::Parse($number)`

Then you can convert the `BigInt` to a `byte array` using `ToByteArray()`.
However the resulting array needs to be "padded" to 16 bytes and reversed (Host vs Network order).

This works for me:

```
function Convert-NumberToIPv6
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$number
    )
     
    $ipv6Decimal  = [System.Numerics.BigInteger]::Parse($number)
    $ipv6Bytes = $ipv6Decimal.ToByteArray()
    # pad to 16 bytes
    [Array]::Resize([ref]$ipv6Bytes, 16)

    # reverse the bytes
    [Array]::Reverse($ipv6Bytes)
    
    # provide a scope identifier to prevent "cannot find overload error"
    $ipAddress = New-Object Net.IPAddress($ipv6Bytes, 0)
    $ipAddress.ToString()
}
```

So the output for: `Convert-NumberToIPv6 -number '281470698520576'` is `::ffff:1.0.0.0`

Comment: Nice! For improved error handling, you might want to check `$ipv6Bytes.Count -le 16`, instead of just trimming to 16 bytes.

Comment: @Remko When I am converting the decimal to ipv6 `Convert-NumberToIPv6 -number '281470698520576' is ::ffff:1.0.0.0` it's actually ipv4 mapped ipv6 address any idea how to separate this with actual ipv6

Answer (score 0):

Using **PowerShell 7+**, here is a possible implementation that works similar to the function in your question in that invalid input will be detected and doesn't cause an exception. In this case the function returns "nothing", which converts to `$false` in a boolean context.

If you need compatibility with **Windows PowerShell (5.x)**, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75535232/7571258).

```sh
function Convert-NumberToIPv6
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)] [string] $number
    )

    [Numerics.BigInteger] $bigInt = 0
    if( [Numerics.BigInteger]::TryParse( $number, [ref] $bigInt ) ) {
        # Check that input is in the range of an unsigned 128 bit number
        if( $bigInt.Sign -ge 0 -and $bigInt.GetBitLength() -le 128 ) {
            $bytes = $bigInt.ToByteArray($true, $true)  # unsigned, big-endian
            $zeros = @(0) * (16 - $bytes.Length)        # zeros to preprend to ensure 128 bit length
            $bytes = [byte[]] ($zeros + $bytes)         # prepend zeros
            ([IPAddress] $bytes).ToString()             # convert to IPAddress and then to string
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```sh
if( $ipv6 = Convert-NumberToIPv6 '281470698520576' ) {
    # Conversion successful, output the address in text form
    $ipv6   
}
else {
    "IPv6 conversion failed!"
}
```

**Output:**

```text
::ffff:1.0.0.0
```

Comment: Hey @zett42 thanks could you please let me know how to convert it into cidr notation (i.e using start ipv6 and end ipv6)

Comment: @NaveenKumar You may add [this C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16263105/7571258) using `Add-Type 'INSERT-C#-CODE'`, then use it like `[IPRangeToCidr.CIDR]::Split([IPAddress]'2a01:111:f406:c00::', [IPAddress]'2a01:111:f406:c00:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff') | ForEach ToString` which prints `2a01:111:f406:c00::/64`.

Comment: is there any function or code in powershell instead using c# code

Comment: @NaveenKumar I don't know any.

Comment: thanks can we leverage the same function Get-IpSubnets with some modification mentioned in question.