# How to convert IPV6 range to single CIDR notation using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, ip, ip-address, ipv6, cidr

I am trying to convert IPV6 Address range into single CIDR notation, but unable to find any method using PowerShell which converts it into CIDR notation.

```
startIP = '::ffff:1.0.0.0'
endIP = '::ffff:1.0.0.255'

Output: '::ffff:1.0.0.0/120'
```

*for reference: https://www.ipaddressguide.com/ipv6-cidr*

Comment: Try some IPv6-aware networking tool library, maybe [ipnetwork](https://github.com/lduchosal/ipnetwork) would be a solution?

Comment: You must realize that IPv6 addresses in the `::ffff:0:0/96` range are not IPv6 addresses; they are IPv4 addresses represented as IPv6 addresses so that both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses can be stored in the same format. Such IPv4 addresses represented as IPv6 addresses cannot be source or destination addresses, nor can they be routed or actually used on a network because they are Reserved by IPv6 itself. The _[IANA IPv6 Special-Purpose Address Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv6-special-registry/iana-ipv6-special-registry.xhtml)_ explains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the C# code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16263105/7571258) in PowerShell via `Add-Type`.

```sh
# Windows PowerShell needs -ReferencedAssemblies for BigInteger type
$refAsm = if( $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -le 5 ) { 
              @{ ReferencedAssemblies = 'System.Numerics' } 
          } else { @{} }

Add-Type @refAsm -TypeDefinition @'
using System;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace IPRangeToCidr {
    public struct CIDR {
        private IPAddress address;
        private uint network_length, bits;

        public CIDR(IPAddress address, uint network_length) {
            this.address = address;
            this.network_length = network_length;
            this.bits = AddressFamilyBits(address.AddressFamily);
            if (network_length > bits) {
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid network length " + network_length + " for " + address.AddressFamily);
            }
        }

        public IPAddress NetworkAddress {
            get { return address; }
        }
        public IPAddress LastAddress {
            get { return IPAddressAdd(address, (new BigInteger(1) << (int) HostLength) - 1); }
        }
        public uint NetworkLength {
            get { return network_length; }
        }
        public uint AddressBits {
            get { return bits; }
        }
        public uint HostLength {
            get { return bits - network_length; }
        }

        override public String ToString() {
            return address.ToString() + "/" + NetworkLength.ToString();
        }

        public String ToShortString() {
            if (network_length == bits) return address.ToString();
            return address.ToString() + "/" + NetworkLength.ToString();
        }

        /* static helpers */
        public static IPAddress IPAddressAdd(IPAddress address, BigInteger i) {
            return IPFromUnsigned(IPToUnsigned(address) + i, address.AddressFamily);
        }

        public static uint AddressFamilyBits(AddressFamily family) {
            switch (family) {
            case AddressFamily.InterNetwork:
                return 32;
            case AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6:
                return 128;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid address family " + family);
            }
        }

        private static BigInteger IPToUnsigned(IPAddress addr) {
            /* Need to reverse addr bytes for BigInteger; prefix with 0 byte to force unsigned BigInteger
             * read BigInteger bytes as: bytes[n] bytes[n-1] ... bytes[0], address is bytes[0] bytes[1] .. bytes[n] */
            byte[] b = addr.GetAddressBytes();
            byte[] unsigned = new byte[b.Length + 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < b.Length; ++i) {
                unsigned[i] = b[(b.Length - 1) - i];
            }
            unsigned[b.Length] = 0;
            return new BigInteger(unsigned);
        }

        private static byte[] GetUnsignedBytes(BigInteger unsigned, uint bytes) {
            /* reverse bytes again. check that now higher bytes are actually used */
            if (unsigned.Sign < 0) throw new ArgumentException("argument must be >= 0");
            byte[] data = unsigned.ToByteArray();
            byte[] result = new byte[bytes];
            for (int i = 0; i < bytes && i < data.Length; ++i) {
                result[bytes - 1 - i] = data[i];
            }
            for (uint i = bytes; i < data.Length; ++i) {
                if (data[i] != 0) throw new ArgumentException("argument doesn't fit in requested number of bytes");
            }
            return result;
        }

        private static IPAddress IPFromUnsigned(BigInteger unsigned, System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily family) {
            /* IPAddress(byte[]) constructor picks family from array size */
            switch (family) {
            case System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork:
                return new IPAddress(GetUnsignedBytes(unsigned, 4));
            case System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6:
                return new IPAddress(GetUnsignedBytes(unsigned, 16));
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("AddressFamily " + family.ToString() + " not supported");
            }
        }

        /* splits set [first..last] of unsigned integers into disjoint slices { x,..., x + 2^k - 1 | x mod 2^k == 0 }
         *  covering exaclty the given set.
         * yields the slices ordered by x as tuples (x, k)
         * This code relies on the fact that BigInteger can't overflow; temporary results may need more bits than last is using.
         */
        public static IEnumerable<Tuple<BigInteger, uint>> split(BigInteger first, BigInteger last) {
            if (first > last) yield break;
            if (first < 0) throw new ArgumentException();
            last += 1;
            /* mask == 1 << len */
            BigInteger mask = 1;
            uint len = 0;
            while (first + mask <= last) {
                if ((first & mask) != 0) {
                    yield return new Tuple<BigInteger, uint>(first, len);
                    first += mask;
                }
                mask <<= 1;
                ++len;
            }
            while (first < last) {
                mask >>= 1;
                --len;
                if ((last & mask) != 0) {
                    yield return new Tuple<BigInteger, uint>(first, len);
                    first += mask;
                }
            }
        }

        public static IEnumerable<CIDR> split(IPAddress first, IPAddress last) {
            if (first.AddressFamily != last.AddressFamily) {
                throw new ArgumentException("AddressFamilies don't match");
            }
            AddressFamily family = first.AddressFamily;
            uint bits = AddressFamilyBits(family); /* split on numbers returns host length, CIDR takes network length */
            foreach (Tuple<BigInteger, uint> slice in split(IPToUnsigned(first), IPToUnsigned(last))) {
                yield return new CIDR(IPFromUnsigned(slice.Item1, family), bits - slice.Item2);
            }
        }
    }
}
'@
```

**Usage example:**

```sh
$startIP = '::ffff:1.0.0.0'
$endIP = '::ffff:1.0.0.255'

[IPRangeToCidr.CIDR]::Split( [IPAddress] $startIP, [IPAddress] $endIP) | 
    ForEach-Object ToString
```

**Output:**

```text
::ffff:1.0.0.0/120
```