# transferring IpAddress from c# to UINT32

Tags: c#, c++

On C# side i'm using `System.Net.IPAddress`

On C++ side i'm using `UINT32` (the result of `inet_addr` function)

In interface of C++-Cli wrapper what would be better to use?
I've tried to use `UINT32` but I don't know how to convert `System.Net.IPAddress` to proper `UINT32` on C# side.

Comment: So the real question is how to convert an IPAdress to a 32 bit integer? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/461742/how-to-convert-an-ipv4-address-into-a-integer-in-c

Comment: @flup if the suggested interface of transffering IPAddress from C# to c++ is 32bit integer then yes. But probably another type is better to be used in cli-wrapper...

Comment: There's the matter of bigendian versus little endian, so perhaps you'd rather use a String then?

Comment: 32-bit will only work for IPv4 addresses.

Comment: that's fine to support only IPv4...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[How to convert an IPv4 address into a integer in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461742/how-to-convert-an-ipv4-address-into-a-integer-in-c)
Take notice that in C++ (like in C# too) uint32 is really unsigned int. You need to convert IpAdress to integer.