# How to calculate number of hosts between two ips? c#

Tags: c#, algorithm, ip

I have two ips:

```
1. 1.1.1.1
2. 4.4.4.4
```

obviously this is just an example, this is a dynamic calculator

how do i calculate number of hosts between said ips if subnet mask is irrelevant?

Comment: Would that be the number of theorietically possible IP addresses or the number of usable IP addresses?

Comment: You can see the IPs as 4-digit 256-based numbers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To calculate the number of (theoretical) IP addresses you would convert each IP address to it's 32 bit integer format (which is actually what it really is), then it's just a matter of simple subtraction:

```
1.1.1.1 = 0x01010101 = 16843009
4.4.4.4 = 0x04040404 = 67372036
```

Number of addresses excluding the start and end address:

```
67372036 - 16843009 - 1 = 50529026
```

Number of addresses including the start and end address:

```
67372036 - 16843009 + 1 = 50529028
```

The number of actual usable addresses would be somewhat lower. Normally a few addresses in each C range is reserved for things like the gateway (router).

Comment: Shouldn't you use `+2`/`-2` instead of `1`?

Comment: @CustomX: No. Look for example at the numbers between 5 and 7; there are 3 numbers including the start and end (5,6,7) and 1 number excluding the start and end (6). The difference between 5 and 7 is 2, so the number of numbers including start and end is 2 + 1 and the number of numbers excluding start and end is 2 - 1.

Answer (score 1):

IPv4 address can be represented by an integer (4 bytes, 32 bits)

To simplify the question, assuming

- All IP addresses are usable
- One host per IP address

Then, [converting both IP addresses to integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461742/how-to-convert-an-ipv4-address-into-a-integer-in-c) and work out the difference would be the number of hosts available.

Comment: This answer would be much more useful if you showed how to convert the IP address to an integer.