# How to calculate number of addresses between two IPv6 addresses

Tags: ipv6

i found this link for How to calculate number of hosts between two ips
for ipv4 [How to calculate number of hosts between two ips? c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27150879/how-to-calculate-number-of-hosts-between-two-ips-c-sharp)

is there any calculation like that for ipv6
for example between: 2a00:1288:110:8b1::2000 and 2a00:1288:110:8b1::21f9

Please help

Comment: It's just hexadecimal math. You can do that in just about any language. But the number of _hosts_ between those two addresses is usually zero, not the same as the number of _addresses_.

Comment: changed the title from hosts to ips

Comment: There are only two IPs (IPv4 and IPv6). IP means Internet Protocol. The title doesn't make any real sense. Perhaps you mean, "_How to calculate number of addresses between two IPv6 addresses_?"

Comment: did you have a language in mind? If the answer you want is hosts, do you need to take into account that a host normally gets a /64?

Comment: in perl or shell or python or as simple linux command

Answer (score 1):

An IPv6 address is a 128 bit number. Like the IPv4 example, use the language functions to convert it to this number and take the differences between the two.