# Convert IP Address to UInt32/UInt64 in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I have a v4 IP Address. I need to convert it to UInt32.
In regular .NET, I was using:

```
string address = "192.168.1.1";
long intAddress = (long)(uint)IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder((int)IPAddress.Parse(address).Address);
```

But IPAddress.Address is not available in .NET Core.
What's the replacement?

Comment: Because I'm geocoding the address against a table that has the ip addresses in UInt32 format.

Comment: @Quantic IPv4 is stored as 4 bytes. `uint` is stored as 4 bytes. Call me crazy, but I think there's a straight-forward conversion.

Comment: @Abion47 dang I'm just filled with bad comments at the moment, you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var address = IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder((int)BitConverter.ToUInt32(IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress).GetAddressBytes(), 0));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [GetAddressBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/api/system.net.ipaddress#System_Net_IPAddress_GetAddressBytes)

`var intAddress = BitConverter.ToInt32(IPAddress.Parse(address).GetAddressBytes(), 0);`

Also:
[How to convert an IPv4 address into a integer in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461742/how-to-convert-an-ipv4-address-into-a-integer-in-c)

Comment: Do I need to worry about big-endian/little-endian environment with this method?

Comment: I don't think so. It looks platform independent [in the source](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/93bde6d2b0cc0797ffb0dca470836ac7f86f876d/src/System.Net.Primitives/src/System/Net/IPAddress.cs#L222-L246)

Comment: If you're storing your value as a `UInt32`, endianness will be a potential concern no matter what operation you're using but if this value will always stay used within a .NET context then it shouldn't ever be a problem. If you're worried about it, though, it might be better to store the IP address as a byte array (or even just a string).

Comment: Yeah, this gives a different result from (long)(uint)IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder((int)IPAddress.Parse(address).Address);

Comment: @user1054922 You've actually just given an example of endianness being a problem. Converting both this answer and the other answer into byte arrays (using "127.0.0.1" as the input), one lists `[127, 0, 0, 1]` while the other lists `[1, 0, 0, 127]`.