# What kind of results can I expect from Request.UserHostAddress?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to save the IP addresses of my users to uniquely identify them - I want to avoid using an account system. According to [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577496/how-can-i-get-the-clients-ip-address-in-asp-net-mvc) to this question, I need to use Request.UserHostAddress.

However, I want to save the IP addresses not as strings but as integers. I already created a function to convert regular IPv4 addresses to their numeric equivalent. What kind of formats (as strings) can I expect to get from Request.UserHostAddress? I want to expand my function to deal with IPv6 addresses, too, but I want to know the different kinds of formats I could get out of Request.UserHostAddress, especially considering how you can shorten IPv6 addresses.

Comment: Rather than parsing it on your own, have you considered using an out-of-the-box [IPAddress class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) for this?

Comment: @Andrei =O Now I feel like an idiot, how did I never find this? Should've used "parser" in my searches instead of "ip address to number"... Yeah, I guess if I can get the numeric value out of it after turning it into an IPAddress instance, then you pretty much answered my question. Add it as an answer if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than worrying about specific formats this property may throw at you, consider using an IP wrapper class that is shipped in System.Net: [IPAddress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.parse(v=vs.110).aspx).

It provides static `Parse(string)` method that handles both IPv4 and IPv6. It also can give you the address as an array of bytes with `GetAddressBytes()`, which you can convert to a numerical value as needed (here is a [code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40410600/728795) of how to do it).