# Int array as a key in a Dictionary VS a string

Tags: c#, string, dictionary, unity-game-engine, int

I have a dictionary right now that is using a `string` as the Key, and a `GameObject` as the value.

The strings are all IP address's, so they are not very long. Here is an example:

```
string ip = "192.68.137.1"
```

I know that number comparisons are much faster than strings, and I am able to parse the IP address's in my database server.

Would it be faster to use an integer array as the KEY for the dictionary? Like this:

```
int[] ip = { 192, 168, 137, 1 }
```

I am checking if the dictionary contains certain values on a regular basis, and also adding to the dictionary regularly (At least once a second normally).

The reason that I am confused about this is because the strings that I am using (the IP address's) are always going to be around that length, so would there be any real benefit to using an integer array? If the dictionary would have to loop through 4 numbers every time, I don't know how much faster that is than a string comparison.

Comment: Better yet, you can simply use an int as a key. IPs are basically a list of 4 bytes (so pretty much an int). For example, "192.68.137.1" is equivalent to 0xc0a88901.

Comment: The IP address would fit in one Int32 :)

Comment: How could I convert either those strings or the array into one int?

Comment: Nitpicking: `int[] ip = [192,168, 137,1]` is not valid c#. Should be `int[] ip = {192,168, 137,1}` (i.e. curly brackets)

Comment: Convertion of the array is simple, array[0] + 256*array[1] + (256^2)*array[2] + (256^3)*array[3]. Just remember that you are effectively in a number system with digits in 0..255.

Comment: Since this is done once in a sec, that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As ever, you should *test* performance rather than guessing about it or asking others to guess. However, two things to think about:

- You've shown an IPv4 address... what about IPv6? That could definitely complicate things
- The IPv4 address is really 4 *bytes*... so why not convert that into a single `uint` or `IPAddress` as the key? That way you don't need to write your own `EqualityComparer<int[]>`. It's a shame `IPAddress` doesn't implement `IEquatable<IPAddress>`, but it looks like it *does* override `Equals`/`GetHashCode` appropriately.

I'd consider the first point, write detailed benchmarks which work out how important this really is - if you're *really* only looking up about once per second, it's very unlikely to be important at all - and then try the various options. I would only move away from the simplest code (which would be a string if that's how you're already receiving the IP address) if you can show a proven, significant improvement.

Comment: My first question was also "how about IPv6 which has different formats?"

Comment: Thank you very much, this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/461742/how-to-convert-an-ipv4-address-into-a-integer-in-c)  was also very helpful for me.

Answer (score 4):

I'd probably use an IPAddress as the key.  I'm assuming (though you could test) that it would be an efficient search on its hash, and the whole v4/v6 thing would be handled for you by the data type.

Answer (score 3):

You can use IPAdress class as Key in your Dictionary.
Example for create from string: 
`var ipAddressString = "192.68.137.1"
IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse(ipAddressString)`

This is a more right way. 
Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.parse(v=vs.110).aspx