# How can I convert an IP address to an integer in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

My primary goal is to filter out a range of IP addresses in IPv4 format by converting them to integers. So, for example, I'd like to filter an IP range from 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.100, but I first need to convert them to integers: 3232235777 to 3232235876.

Is there a way to do this in BigQuery (standard SQL)? I've looked at the BigQuery documentation but my combination of the `NET.IP_FROM_STRING()` and `NET.IPV4_TO_INT64()` functions keeps throwing this error: `No matching signature for function NET.IPV4_TO_INT64 for argument types: STRING.`

```
SELECT addr_str, ip_from_string, FORMAT("0x%X",
  NET.IPV4_TO_INT64(ip_from_string)) AS ipv4_to_int64
FROM
(
SELECT addr_str, FORMAT("%T", NET.IP_FROM_STRING(addr_str)) AS ip_from_string
FROM UNNEST(['192.168.1.1','192.168.1.100']) AS addr_str
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you calling `FORMAT` on the result of `NET.IP_FROM_STRING`? `NET.IP_FROM_STRING` returns the IP address as bytes, and using that you can convert to an INT64 using `NET.IPV4_TO_INT64`, for example.

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  addr_str,
  ip_from_string,
  NET.IPV4_TO_INT64(ip_from_string) AS ipv4_to_int64
FROM (
  SELECT
    addr_str,
    NET.IP_FROM_STRING(addr_str) AS ip_from_string
  FROM UNNEST(['192.168.1.1','192.168.1.100']) AS addr_str
);
```

Comment: Thanks, Elliot. I called mindlessly called the `FORMAT` function simply because that's what was in the Google documentation haha.

Answer (score 2):

[`NET.IPV4_TO_INT64`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#netipv4_to_int64) function expects binary (BYTES) as an input, but you "accidentally" cast ip_from_string to string by applying [`FORMAT`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#format) function.

Just remove it!

Comment: Thanks as always, Mikhail!

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/461770/33611) covers the math of converting an IPv4 to an integer. Are there mathematical operators available to you in BigQuery?