# C# - How to show every combination of a 3 decimal placed number (4 numbers outside of the decimals)

Tags: c#, int, decimal, digit

I am wondering how to write all the possible combinations of a number with 3 decimals in it.

As you might have guessed I am using this for IP addresses, so I need the numbers for the 4 decimal places to be between 0 and 255.
Is there any way I can write in a console application every combination of a 4 decimal place number (0.0.0.0 - 255.255.255.255)? If this can be done, a reply would be awesome. Thanks for reading!

Comment: Everything in the world is doable if we try. So go ahead and give it a try, post your efforts here, and then come up with specific issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was messing around with this project for awhile, but didn't know what code sample to post here because I was unsure what could be relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this with simple nested for loops like this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < 256; a++)
        {
           for (int b = 0; b < 256; b++)
           {
               for (int c = 0; c < 256; c++) 
               {
                   for (int d = 0; d < 256; d++)
                   {
                       string ipAddress = string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", a, b, c, d);
                       Console.WriteLine(ipAddress);
                   }
               }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly! Appreciate the fast response.

Comment: @TamásSzabó Your edit doesn´t make this answer even any more readable, it´s quite okay as it is.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Alright, I guess it's just personal opinion then.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Just out of curiosity, are you against using `using` blocks the same fashion too?

Comment: @TamásSzabó I don´t have anything against this style, my comment was just related to your edit which didn´t introduced any improvement - but no harm however.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can [convert an IP4 address to integer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13350494/205233), you could do this in one for loop:

```
for (uint i = 0; i <= 4294967295; i++)
{
    byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(i);
    Array.Reverse(bytes);
    string ipAddress = new IPAddress(bytes).ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(ipAddress);
}
```