# System.Net.IPAddress.Address' is obsolete

Tags: c#, ip-address

I try to convert Ip Address to `uint`:

```
IPAddress requstedIpAddress;
uint requesteIpAddressUint = (uint)IPAddress.Parse(requstedIpAddress.ToString()).Address;
```

And got this warning:

> 'System.Net.IPAddress.Address' is obsolete: 'This property has been
>   deprecated. It is address family dependent. Please use
>   IPAddress.Equals method to perform comparisons.

What does it mean and should i use some other way to do that ?

Comment: what are all the libraries you have imported?

Comment: IPv6 address does not fit to `uint`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse an IP address string to a uint value in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36831/how-do-you-parse-an-ip-address-string-to-a-uint-value-in-c)

Comment: This should give you the same result as above without the warning,
uint requesteIpAddressUint = BitConverter.ToUInt32(requstedIpAddress.GetAddressBytes(),0);

Although it will only work for IPv4.

Comment: LOL and yet here we are 8yrs later still with this error message! Maybe the next release? ;)

Answer (score 6):

The deprecation warning tells you that in the next update of your library which has `IPAddress` defined, will no longer have `IPAddress.Address` as a property. So your code will fail to compile after the next update to the library.

If you go to the documentation for [IPAddress.Address](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.address(v=vs.110).aspx) it notes that the property is obsolete and should instead use [IPAddress.GetAddressBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.getaddressbytes(v=vs.110).aspx).

The deprecation of `IPAddress.Address` is due to the adoption of IPv6 which is 128 bits while C# type `long`, which is actually a [System.Int64](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctetwysk.aspx), is only 64 bits.

Comment: So it's better using IPAddress.GetAddressBytes, what about if i have an IPv^ address ?

Comment: `IPAddress.GetAddressBytes` returnes `bytes[]` so that its can support IP address v4 and v6 and possibly next iterations though thats not likely for some time.